# Unable to update in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've encountered a problem regarding updating the value in the database table named "answers".As it is not updating the table. So, here it`s my code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['marked']))
            { $marked= $_POST['marked'];
            $command= "UPDATE Answers SET " .
          "SessionID=" . $_POST['SessionID'] . ", " .
          "TestID=" . $_POST['TestID'] . ", " .
          "QuesID=" . $_POST['QuesID'] . ", " .
          "A1=0, " .
          "A2=0, " .
          "A3=0, " .
          "A4=0, " .
          "A5=0, " .
          "A6=0, " .
          "AnswerText=\"\", " .
          "SortOrder='" . intval($_POST['Order']) . "' " .
          "marked=1".
          "WHERE SessionID=" . $_POST['SessionID'] .
          " AND QuesID=" . $_POST['QuesID'];
             $lolsql= mysql_query($command, $conn);


             }
```

I want to update the 'marked' field having 0 value  to 1 whenever someone is clicking on the marked(submit button).
Please someone helps me. Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: ***warning*** your code is *extremely vulnerable* to sql injection attacks! converting your code to using something like prepared statements will solve your issue as well.

Comment: you are also missing the `,` character after `SortOrder=''`

Comment: Well, the database library has some features to tell you more about the error. Use it. Also check for error return values: http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extremenly vulnerable to injection attacks because you are not at all sanitizing your inputs and directly updating your datbase, secondly start using `mysqli_()` or `PDO statements`, `mysql_()` is no more maintained by the community.

Atleast use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize your input

Example

```
if(isset($_POST['whatever'])) {
  $holder = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection, $_POST['value']);
}
```

And your query is total mess, why are you using concatenation? cant you simply write your query like this?

```
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET col_name = '$value', col_name2 = '$value2' ... WHERE ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Complete code:**

```
<? if(isset($_POST['marked'])) {

    $answer_text = "something here";

    $marked = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['marked']);
    $session = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['SessionID']);
    $test = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TestID']);
    $ques = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['QuesID']);
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string($answer_text);
    $order = intval(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Order']));

    mysql_query("
    UPDATE
        `Answers`

    SET
        `SessionID` = '$session',
        `TestID` = '$test',
        `QuesID` = '$que',
        `A1` = 0,
        `A2` = 0,
        `A3` = 0,
        `A4` = 0,
        `A5` = 0,
        `A6` = 0,
        `AnswerText` = '$answer',
        `SortOrder` = '$order',
        `marked` = 1

    WHERE
        `SessionID` = '$session'
        AND
            `QuesID` = '$ques';
    ") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

}?>
```

**If you prefer to have the query on one line:**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `Answers` SET `SessionID` = '$session', `TestID` = '$test', `QuesID` = '$que', `A1` = 0, `A2` = 0, `A3` = 0, `A4` = 0, `A5` = 0, `A6` = 0, `AnswerText` = '$answer', `SortOrder` = '$order', `marked` = 1 WHERE `SessionID` = '$session' AND `QuesID` = '$ques';") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

If you're still having trouble, this script will return an error starting with `Error:`. You may have misspelt one of the columns.

Comment: If this helps answer your question, please remember to mark it as answered!